# To use codeigniter framework or standard php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

Discussed this with a developer as I suggested to use CodeIgniter framework over standard PHP.

Their response was as follows:

> Advantages of Code Igniter include standardised MVC structure.
>   Disadvantages include the fact that you need the whole framework even if you dont need to use it all and also a bit slower for the team to roll out the project. Advantages of our normal Custom PHP framework - fast to develop and totally flexible, only need the code that is relevant.

Would you agree with their response and why?
I always though CI was quicker to roll out due to the use of short tags and freely available modules.

Comment: the guy sounds like he is trying to get you to use his framework over codeigniter's. any framework's goal is to speed up development, and each has advantages and disadvatages. I can't see codeigniter slowing you down because it has more features. It's not like you have to use them all. Assuming you know what you are looking for, you just learn and use what is relevant.

Comment: Btw. What is his framework? Does he have a base of successful projects based on his framework? And what does he implement, if not MVC? For me it seems like the guy does not know CodeIgniter (or any other non-custom) framework and fears to start the project based on it. But it is only a guess and he may be quite good at coding, and this framework can be very good - it is just my guess based on how he argumented his framework is better.

Comment: @Tadeck: I'm unsure what the 'custom' framework is. The dev is for the backend admin and backend business area for an iPhone app.

Comment: I think the guy your talking to his incompetent and I would like to even see if his so-called framework is even a real MVC.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- CodeIgniter has a learning curve but that curve is likely to be quicker than your custom framework. That's because CodeIgniter is well documented.
- CodeIgniter is a fairly comprehensive library. Once you learn the framework, you can employ any of its libraries not only in the current project but in various other projects.
- The work is already done for you. You may not even know that a XSS or CSRF exploit exists in your code because you haven't done a thorough security audit. But a community framework is under constant audit.
- You can extend CodeIgniter to your own needs and still have custom functionality.
- After using CodeIgniter for a sufficient period of time, you'll inevitably pick up some great programming practices and improve your overall knowledge since the framework employs many best practies.
- It is likely that if you encounter a problem situation, someone else has already solved it. CodeIgniter also has a good community through which you could save yourself hours of debugging.

That said, CodeIgniter is not the only framework but I really do like that fact that with the newer release they have moved to PHP5. In general, open source frameworks are the way to go.

Comment: perfect! Just what I was looking for ;) you confirmed exactly what I suspected.

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly disagree.

The details of the project would be very helpful, but in general **frameworks are very helpful and speed up the work (not necessarily the application) significantly**.

Consider the fact, that 'Custom PHP Framework' (whatever they think of) is... custom. That means it is not tested as eg. Zend Framework, it has not proven to be efficient and successful in thousands of projects, and it is probably something very simple (as large frameworks have been developed for years by big teams of developers plus the developers of companies that use them).

Of course coding PHP can be quite good option, when you really need speed (of the application), have time to build it and money to pay the developers that will be developing it quite extensively (because they will be implementing many features that come with almost every PHP framework). But you have to be sure, that you *really* need to take that non-standard approach (as 'non-standard' I mean not using some reliable framework).

It is up to you. If you can give some details about the application that has to be created, the answers may be more relevant.

Comment: ... they are also so heavy they need to implement a cache system to work...

Comment: @Charliepiga do have some specific framework in mind?

Comment: any heavily used webpage sooner or later will need caching

Comment: @Tadeck... mmm everyone?

Comment: @Charliepiga it depends - in some applications you do not _have_ to implement any caching: it just may not be needed

Comment: Thanks guys. I thought the same. @Tadeck: basically the iPhone app connects up to the backend admin and business areas (including the DB). Most pages will sit in the admin and business areas.

Answer (score 4):

> Non-Business projects: Standard PHP.
>   Business projects: CI.

Trying to build you own Framework is very educative and will help you a lot; it will also let you create a framework that fit your needs instead of a general one. But that could be done only if you are managing to create a non Business projects because Business ones requires stability that you may not get from a home-made framework. By creating your own framework you might loose a lot of time (which is expensive when working with business stuff) and money for nothing.

It basically depends on your project type.

Comment: even for non-business projects.using mvc frameworks make you learn a lot..

Answer (score 2):

I have some experience with writing my own CMS, and I must admit, that this was very educating, but from financial point of view, totally uneconomic decision.

In my opinion, those developers should try to write some specification. Very detailed specification of what they need to implement. Then they should calculate time needed to code such functionality so they can compare this work to elements already included in CI and decide which option is more viable in terms of time to code, time to learn, and of course time to test.

Comment: -1 CI is not a CMS, it is an MVC framework.

Comment: You're right. But my answer is still correct :)

Answer (score 2):

If they don't mind teaching their custom framework, then it's probably the best fit (especially if the guy who wrote it is still around).

However, custom frameworks can turn into unsupportable nightmares.  CI has the advantage of a small community and thorough documentation.  Once you roll out a few projects with it, I'm sure the roll-out time will be as fast as the custom framework.

Answer (score 2):

We ditched our own custom framework in favour of CI.  Financially it was a tough decision as weve spent 1000's of hours on it and have a lot of projects running on it.

CI has allowed us to develop faster and has standardised our projects.  The architecture also allows us to extend easily without concerns about 'damaging' the core framework.

CI is the way forward IMO

Answer (score 1):

Their response was quasi-correct...

> ```
>    Disadvantage: also a bit slower for the team to roll out the project.
> ```

This is generally untrue, and infact, it's probably quite the contrary in many cases. Personally, I am able to crank out projects *much* faster using a framework. I haven't used MVC in a team environment but I would imagine that by dividing work into Models, Views and Controllers workflow seperations would promote development speed.

What are you building? This is the crucial question.

If you're building a dynamic web application, frameworks will save you hours and hours of work because you won't have to reinvent the wheel over and over again. If the point of your project is basic, then indeed... frameworks add too much overhead. I'd say, as a general rule, if you're project will require greater than 5 .php files, then start using a framework, because that's what it's purpose is - to separate the logic.

Use CodeIgniter or another framework for larger projects where you suspect your code will start to get disorganised. The MVC pattern prevents this disorganisation.

It sounds as if you've never used a framework before. The first step in making decisions on whether or not a framework will suit the task is to get familiar with one. You'll then be in a much better position to make this call. I do not recommend you write your own right away; you will gain a lot of insight after playing around with CI, Cake, or Zend.

Comment: arsenault: basically an iPhone app connects up to the backend admin and business areas (including the DB). Most pages will sit in the admin and business areas.